# How to get reader id who has checked out most books from library in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am trying to make a query in database to get the reader_id who has checked out books most. Here is my table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| checkoutID | bookID | readerID | date_checked_out | 
-----------------------------------------------------
|     1      |    1   |     1    |    01/01/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     2      |    3   |     1    |    01/01/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     3      |   15   |     2    |    01/03/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     4      |   12   |     1    |    01/04/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     5      |    3   |     3    |    01/05/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     6      |   30   |     3    |    01/06/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     7      |    5   |     2    |    01/08/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     8      |    2   |     2    |    01/08/2016    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     9      |    1   |     3    |    01/08/2016    | 
-----------------------------------------------------
|    10      |   33   |     3    |    01/19/2016    | 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

So my question is that how I can get readerID who has checked out most books in total. So by counting total rows in checkout by readerID how can I get readerID with most checkout?

In this case I should get `readerID = 3` which is the answer that I am looking for. Can anyone tell me how I can do it? I have never done this kind of query so I am asking!

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT *, count(`checkoutID`) as `total_ds` FROM `checkout`;` which gives me everything in one row plus `total_ids` = `10`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a `GROUP BY` and get the result with the highest `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT readerID
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY readerID
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Worked it like awesome. Thanks. You saved my day. :D